# Issue on setting the background image on group in expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a ExpandableListView and i am setting the background image when the group is expanded,
but issue occur that when i set the background image size is changed to current background of group,

any help ??

see below image

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is different in your Image size, so its changing height according your Image size as you would take `WRAP_CONTENT` in Height.

Do fix your height or make sure that both Image are with same height and width.